# Proxy Configuration Angular 2 for Spring Boot w/out Angular CLI and ng serve

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http-proxy, package.json

I have a frontend app built on angular 2 and a backend app built on java EE via spring boot and maven within eclipse neon.  They are configured on different ports within my localhost for development, and I need to proxy my angular app to use the backend java project.

I started by creating a proxy.config.json file such as this:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target":"http://localhost:8080",
    "secure":false
  }
}
```

My `package.json` file is not directly using angular cli for the start command, it is calling another build process and it is within this other build process (another json package) where I can set the port, directory, etc.  So long story short, how can I call a proxy from my frontend to my backend without using angular cli and `ng serve` in the start command of my package.json file?  How can I call my `proxy.config.json` file to run without using `ng serve`?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting your webpack if not through ng serve???

Comment: Within the `package.json` scripts section, the start command executes a custom build process (custom-build-config.json), and within that custom build process we have a `bundle` section where we are setting a `webpack` property equal to `true`.  It is in this custom build several javascript files are analyzing the properties from the custom-build library.  In looking through it's js files, I do not see a property for proxy configuration.  I was mainly wondering if angular had that built in aside from angular cli

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have a development build and a production build.

`ng serve` starts the development server on a specific port (eg: 4200). By default the build is the development build unless you specify `ng serve --prod`.

Therefore, for development purposes, you can setup your proxy to forward specific calls (eg: http://localhost:80/ui) to your development server launched using `ng serve`, hence to `http://localhost:4200` by default. Then access the Angular app through your proxy (eg: http://localhost:80/ui).

On production you would create a production build using `ng build --prod`, place the build on a server and setup the proxy to forward specific calls to that server.

Let me know if I missed something.